# Remove vertical scrollbar and design the horizontal only

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

1. Tying to remove vertical scrollbar and keep the mouse wheel but its remove also the horizontal scrollbar from list or other `div`.

   ```
   body {
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }

   ::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 0 !important
   }
   ```
2. How can I design the horizontal scrollbar only using css/js and add mouse wheel?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by Keep Mouse Wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
body{
      width:500px;
      background-color: grey;
    }
#div1{
  background-color:blue; 
  width:500px; 
  height:500px; 
  overflow-x:scroll;
  }
#div2{
  background-color:red; 
  width:600px; 
  height:300px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
 
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <div id="div2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
#main{
  
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:red;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:none;
  }
```

```html
<div id='main'>
  
  </div>
```

Comment: add div tag into the body tag and fix the body tag width. i think it's works

Comment: try another example

Answer (score 0):

For removing vertical scroll bar

```
body{
 overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: http://www.dte.web.id/2013/02/event-mouse-wheel.html this link may help you Scopi

Answer (score 0):

```css
#divId{width:400px;height:200px;background:magenta;}
#wrap{width:200px;height:100px;
overflow-x:scroll;}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="divId"></div></div>
```